# Download file directly from dropbox (no sign in)

Tags: dropbox

Is there a way to download file directly from dropbox without logging in.  I find this to be a serious limitation.  I want to link a few files from website.  Can this be done in dropbox?

I realise this can be done with an api (at least in theory) but I have no idea what the link should look like. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Dropbox shared link for a file that can be accessed publicly, you can download from it programmatically.

You can download directly using the link as documented here:

https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download

Or, you can use the API via the /2/sharing/get_shared_link_file endpoint:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file